# How to run test cases belonging to a particular group in parallel using TestNG

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

How to run test cases belonging to a particular group in parallel using TestNG.
For example, let say there is a group named "up" containing 10 test cases. I want to run all these test cases in parallel (threads=number of test cases). How can I achieve in using TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `testng.xml`. If you don't know the number of test cases before you run your code, just be sure that the `threadCount` is higher than it :)

```
  <suite parallel="methods" threadCount="10">    
    <test name="MyTest">
      <groups>
        <run>
          <include name="up"  />
        </run>
      </groups>

      <classes>
        <class name="test.TestClass" />
      </classes>
    </test>
  </suite>
```

Comment: My requirement is, run only a particular test group test cases in parallel. Using the above, it will run all test methods in parallel. Suite will be containing multiple packages, classes, methods, groups. In such case this won't help the way I want.